# Cloud Functions for Firebase - get database value 'synchronously'

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

My realtime db has this structure

```
- userId1
   - meta
       - name 
   - data 
       - dataId1
           - description 
       - dataId2...
- userId2....
```

I'm trying to monitor additions to dataIdx but want to get the `name` field too. I tried the following, but was misusing the `parent` method. So I thought about the line commented out, but `.once` is asynchronous, which starts to make my code more complex, while in the [examples](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#handle_event_data) there are calls to `set` that are more or less synchronous

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/{userId}/presents/{dataId}')
    .onWrite(event => {
        var eventSnapshot = event.data;
        var person = eventSnapshot.parent().parent().child("meta").child("name").val();
        // var person = admin.database().ref('/' + event.params.userId + '/meta/name').once().val();
        let p = eventSnapshot.child("description").val();
        console.log(`${person} added ${p}`);
```

What would be the correct way to do this

Comment: [`set`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#set) is not synchronous; it returns a promise. It's just that the calling code in the example is not waiting for the `set` call to resolve or error.

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to work on a promises based solution now

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with using chained promises to build my data

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/{userId}/presents/{presentId}')
    .onWrite(event => {
        let p = eventSnapshot.child("description").val();
        return event.data.ref.parent.parent.child('meta/name').once("value")
            .then(snapshot => {
                let person = snapshot.val();

                var payload = {
                    data: {
                        person: person,
                        ...
                    }
                };
```